# Can someone explain the code happening inside the for loop? LSTM prediction

Tags: python, lstm

So I'm going through a machine learning model and I'm met with this code.

```
n_input=12
n_features=1
pred_list = []
batch = train[-n_input:].reshape(1,n_input,n_features)

for i in range(n_input):
    pred_list.append(model.predict(batch)[0]) #predict one value
    batch = np.append(batch[:,1:,:],[[pred_list[i]]],axis=1)#append to the end of the batch list
```

I understand that in batch, it takes the -n_input index values until the end denoted by ":", then reshapes the dataframe into (1,n_input,n_features) which in this case is (1,12,1).

To make a prediction, a for loop is used, and it is looped 12 times equal our n_inputs, n_inputs is the amount of periods into the future I want to forecast.

That's where my confusion begins, I don't quite understand the code inside the for loop. Can someone explain the code inside the loop? Thanks for reading.

The article in question:https://medium.com/swlh/a-quick-example-of-time-series-forecasting-using-long-short-term-memory-lstm-networks-ddc10dc1467d

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a list of 5 values

[1,2,3,4,5]

You want to predict the 10th value.

The first line of that code is making a single prediction 6.

The second line of that code is adding it to the previous list (batch[:,1:,:] is specifying that batch will now increment by one value and [[pred_list[i]]] is adding the recent prediction to the end). So you end up with:

[2,3,4,5,6]

Then you'd restart the loop with the new batch to predict the 7th value.